# Why is ScriptResource.axd compressed, even though IIS compression is disabled?

Tags: asp.net, iis, gzip, http-compression

I run an ASP.NET application on IIS 6.0. Usually I have compression turned on for both dynamic and static files. However, I've turned compression off temporarily, but "ScriptResource.axd" is still sent compressed. This does not feel like a misconfiguration, as "WebResource.axd" is not compressed.

What is the difference between ScriptResource and WebResource, such that the former is still compressed? How is it getting compressed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Resources are handled by the [AssemblyResourceLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.assemblyresourceloader.aspx) class, which is designed to retrieve assembly resources and serve them to the Web browser. Web Resources *are not* compressed by default.

Script Resources are handled by the [ScriptResourceHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.scriptresourcehandler.aspx) class, which takes care of all requests for embedded script files that are referenced through the ScriptManager class.
Script Resources *are* automatically compressed with GZIP by default for HTTP delivery.

Comment: but do you know how to disable its compression? it is needed in URL Rewrite module!