# What is an .axd file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

What kind of purpose do `.axd` files serve?

I know that it is used in the [ASP.Net AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax) and its controls.  I'd like to know more about it.

I tried Googling for it, but could not find getting basic information.

Comment: Does anyone have documentation on how to make them or use them?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

from Google

An .axd file is a HTTP Handler file. There are two types of .axd files.

1. ScriptResource.axd
2. WebResource.axd

These are files which are generated at runtime whenever you use ScriptManager in your Web app. This is being generated only once when you deploy it on the server.

Simply put the ScriptResource.AXD contains all of the clientside javascript routines for Ajax. Just because you include a scriptmanager that loads a script file it will never appear as a ScriptResource.AXD - instead it will be merely passed as the .js file you send if you reference a external script file. If you embed it in code then it may merely appear as part of the html as a  tag and code but depending if you code according to how the ToolKit handles it - may or may not appear as as a ScriptResource.axd. ScriptResource.axd is only introduced with AJAX and you will never see it elsewhere

And ofcourse it is necessary

Comment: They are server side files that render resources to the client `WebResource.axd?d=SbXSD3uTnhYsK4gMD8fL84_mH....` .css and .js files are static

Comment: Maybe sometimes I get errors like ***This is an invalid script resource request.*** _`at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest`_ More info: **ServerVariables_PATH_INFO /v2/ScriptResource.axd**

Answer (score 75):

Those are not files (they don't exist on disk) - they are just names under which some HTTP handlers are registered.
Take a look at the `web.config` in .NET Framework's directory (e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="eurl.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="True" />
      <add path="trace.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" validate="True" />
      <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>
      <add path="*.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="True" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```

You can register your own handlers with a `whatever.axd` name in your application's `web.config`. While you can bind your handlers to whatever names you like, `.axd` has the upside of working on IIS6 out of the box by default (IIS6 passes requests for `*.axd` to the ASP.NET runtime by default). Using an arbitrary path for the handler, like `Document.pdf` (or really anything except ASP.NET-specific extensions), requires more configuration work. In IIS7 in integrated pipeline mode this is no longer a problem, as all requests are processed by the ASP.NET stack.

Answer (score 1):

An AXD file is a file used by ASP.NET applications for handling embedded resource requests. It contains instructions for `retrieving embedded resources, such as images, JavaScript (.JS) files, and.CSS files.` AXD files are used for injecting resources into the client-side webpage and access them on the server in a standard way.