# what is this ScriptResource.axd And WebResource.axd file and why it is loading 10 times in my page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am very confused with this 2 files. when i go to chrome `=>` developer tools `=>`  Resource

I see this 2 files loading over 8-9 times, specially ScriptResource.axd file 6 times.

when i open these file, they have javascript inside it and every file has a diff codes.

i understand from this SO [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879824/what-is-axd-file) that these are ScriptManager file whenever you use Ajax in your app. and also it says that it is generated one time when you deploy. BUT i see it total of 9 times on my local as well as on my server. and each file is taking around 32ms to load, thats what i see in developer tools.

please help me with this and let me know how can i resolve these files to load only once.

thank you for your time.

Comment: Because you are using ScriptManager Control or SqlDataSource on your pages.

Comment: i understand that, BUT it is getting loading 10 times.

Comment: Is not the same code that is loading. The file is the same but generate dynamic code.

Answer (score 0):

It's different scripts.  If you AJAX control toolkit or another ASP.NET AJAX framework, where there are script files embedded into a DLL, all of these scripts are loaded separately and are represented by ScriptResource or WebResource.  They are not all automatically combined into one reference.

Open up IE's debugger tools, FireFox with FireBug, or Chrome Dev tools and take a look at each script.  There's 2 scripts for ASP.NET AJAX, 1 for validator controls, etc.