# Cannot update Sharepoint lists. Post Back undefined?

Tags: sharepoint, webforms, postback

We recently upgraded our 2007 Content Database to SharePoint 2010 and now we are unable to save a list item. When I open IE developer tools i see the error:

SCRIPT5009: 'WebForm_PostBackOptions' is undefined

Is anybody familiar with this or know a fix?

Comment: Can you check (using fiddler/ie9 development console/chrome) network traffic to SharePoint server, when you're initially opening page, if there are no 404/401/500 response codes?

Comment: Yes. I am getting 404s on ScriptResource.axd and all of my JQuery files

Comment: this axd 404 file might be the reason - you can check for example this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879824/what-is-an-axd-file or look for alternative. In one of this axd files `WebForm_PostBackOptions` method is defined.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't say how to fix it in SP2010. Only an explanation of axd and how / why it is generated

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a HTTP redirecting to the root of the site that was tied to our Alternate Access Mappings. I removed this redirect and everything loaded fine with no 404s. This must have been affecting our relative URLs