# ScriptResource.axd is not loading in asp.net ? 500 URL Rewrite Module Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, telerik

I have asp.net website build over ektron V8.0 SP1. I am using url rewrite module in my application.it working as expected.I have telrick controls also in my application.

But unfortunately now am not able to use any of the telrick control in my web page.The reason is:

```
 corresponding ScriptResource.axd resource are not loading as expected.
```

I got this error in my web browser.[image]

When i comment few `<rule.../>`in `<outboundRules>` it start working.

Once i browse from Hosted server the error is

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the 
content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip").
```

Any one have any idea why the script resources are not loading. 
Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add a rule to ignore *.axd as one of your first rules:

```
<rule name="Exclude some stuff" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)\.(asmx|svc|axd)(.*)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.{R:2}{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: i had try this but the issue persist.

Comment: Could you look in the Event Viewer of call one of the axd URLs directly in your browser to get a more detailed error message?

Comment: Is it possible to disable the compression? As suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713804/url-rewrite-outbound-rules-iis7

Comment: I already have `<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />` in my web.config

Comment: Does the Telerik component have its own settings with its own enable-compression flags? Assuming the ScriptResources being loaded are for Telerik. I'm not familiar with the component so don't know about the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what worked for me is to add a new precondition making sure that .AXDs are not checked and add the precondition to the Outbound Rules that are causing the problem:

```
<outboundRules>
   <rule name="ProblemRule" preCondition="noAxd" enabled="true">
      ...
   </rule>
   <preConditions>
       <preCondition name="noAxd">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
       </preCondition>
   </preConditions>
 </outboundRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify a bit more on what exactly ScriptManager are you using on your page? Is it RadScriptManager or it is the asp ScriptManager?

In case you are using RadScriptManager you can double check will the issue be replicated if you replace it with the asp one ("ScriptManager"). In this case the HTTP traffic to the problematic page will be more intensive and descriptive