# Reverse proxy from IIS 8.5 to an azure website

Tags: wordpress, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have a VM in azure with IIS, I'm already running a website in that VM let's say **mysite.com** not I'd like to have my blog in a directory within the website, the blog is a WordPress site hosted separately in another azure website like http://siteblog.azurewebsites.net

[image: reverse proxy]

I've done a reverse proxy with two rules in the IIS, the issue is with the outbound rule, I get the following error:

> Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP
>   response is encoded ("gzip").

Searching on google I found this [article](http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk/iis7-urlrewrite-outbound-links-with-compression-enabled/) and two questions [1](http://forums.iis.net/t/1165899.aspx?URL%20Rewrite%20Outbound%20Rules%20w%20Compression),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713804/url-rewrite-outbound-rules-iis7) all of them practically apply almost the same approach.

According to the article, I have to add a key to the windows registry which as far I know isn't possible.

> On the machine running the web site, from the command line run: reg
>   add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Rewrite /v
>   LogRewrittenUrlEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 You may need to follow this
>   up with an iisreset

my rules in the IIS web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="false">
            <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Img, Link" pattern="^http(s)?://mseblog.azurewebsites.net/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://mysite.com/{R:2}" />
        </rule>

        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://siteblog.azurewebsites.net/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Questions:**

- How can I fix the error?
- Any other approach besides using URL rewriting or reverse proxy?